# Unexpected "CalloutException" only when validating changeset

Tags: unit-test, deployment, callout, change-set

I'm trying to deploy some code.  I've tested everything in sandbox, verified unit tests pass and coverage is good.  Created a changeset, uploaded to Prod.  When I validate the changeset, I get 1 failure, with the following message:

> Changeset "xxx" will not validate. One unit test fails with "An unexpected error occurred when trying to make a callout to the Box API. You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

The exception is one I'm familiar with.   You can't make an HTTP callout if you have DML pending (since the callout may fail or hang).  However:

1. The code was specifically designed to avoid this issue.  I've hand checked the code to ensure there's no DML occurring before the callout.
2. The same test passes in sandbox.  I've double-checked that all relevant code is in the changeset.

The only thing I can think is that some of the unit test setup DML is "leaking" past the Test.startTest() call?  Could this be a Spring 17 issue?  I've opened a case, but client has Standard support; I expect it may be closed as "development issue".  Has anyone else seen this variance between sandbox & validation?

**Edit 1-Mar-17**: At @DanielBallinger's suggestion I was able to capture a log of the failing test execution during the validation attempt.  I see 3 pairs of DML_BEGIN/DML_END, and they are the three inserts I'm doing as part of my test setup; they all occur before Test.startTest().  I also scanned the log from test.startTest() to the error, looking for anything else (WF, etc) that could cause this; I see nothing.  Further, none of the objects involved have any WF or Processes defined.  It certainly looking like a platform issue.

And after 20 minutes on the phone with support, the case was closed because it's a "developer issue" and the client has Standard support.

Comment: Are there any workflows or process builders in production that aren't in the sandbox?  A workflow could be causing a trigger to re-fire or a process builder could be doing the DML.

Comment: Also, depending on API version, if you have a WFR sending an email in production that was not in sandbox it could be causing it. Really it comes down to the difference between production and sandbox. When you find that, you will find the issue....

Comment: Try capturing the Apex Debug logs from the changeset validation. Just ensure the Developer console is open and logging before doing the validation.

Comment: @DanielBallinger That would be a great trick (I've always wanted validation failure apex logs), but it doesn't seem to work for me, I only see a /changemgmt/monitorDeployment.apexp log every 3-4 seconds for the deploy status page refresh. Am I missing something?

Comment: aha - Restarted dev console and used "Run specified tests" for the failing test, and I got a log.  Now to dig...

Comment: What about related objects? Roll ups cause things to happen in them. Any email alerts? That caused issues before but was supposed to have been fixed. What API version is your code?

Comment: @Eric the org has DLRS rollups and a couple email alerts, but none related to any objects in the unit test.  And how would the be triggered except by DML, all of which is before startTest()?  Code versions vary nut nothing older than 33.0; though the code works in Sandbox with those versions.  Still, I'll try updating all code to latest API for comparison.

Comment: Just FYI I have a case escalated to R&D right now around validate deployments. We are not getting an issue similar to yours BUT we are getting different results from tests during validate vs running the test in the developer console. I am not sure if it is related but this issue for us was certainly introduced in Spring 17.

Comment: I've got a case open currently for the same issue. It began after Spring 17, and does not happen on all instances. Test setup DML (creation of a user) seems to be visible within `system.runas(user)` as a result the code throws an uncommitted work callout exception - my example is within a batch context.

Comment: If the information helps your troubleshooting, here's the instances I tested in which throw callout exceptions in my tests and which instances do not. NA11: Pass (1 org); NA22: Fail (6 orgs); NA30: Fail (5 orgs); NA34: Pass (1 org); NA35: Pass (2 orgs)

Comment: @MarkPond aha - I'm trying to deploy to NA30.  Would you mind posting an answer here if you get either a fix or a known issue assigned?

Comment: @JasonClark here's one known issue link which was provided on my case (15879964), which is still open and being escalated. Looks like the workaround is to set the API version of the class which makes the callout to v.33 or lower. 34+ will throw the exception when the test executes. This workaround allows my minimalist reproduction code to pass the test. [W-2979657](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eXOsAAM)

Comment: This related known issue [W-2839839](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jbNMAAY) is similar to my reproduction code. However, querying for an existing user is not a viable work around for my package and test cases. YMMV

Comment: @MarkPond My release was put on hold due to last minute requirements change; as of today the issue still exists.  I tried changing the Apex version of the calling-out class to v33, and the tests now pass.  If you'd like to add an answer to that effect, I will mark accepted.

Comment: I'm experiencing this now as well, and did try reducing API version of the calling classes to 33 - no dice. My production is on NA39. Do I have to reduce API version of test and mock classes as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per two known issues, [W-2979657](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eXOsAAM) and [W-2839839](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jbNMAAY):

The workaround is to set the API version of the class which makes the callout to v.33 or lower. A class with an API version of 34 or higher will inappropriately throw the callout exception when the unit test executes.

This workaround allows my minimalist reproduction code to pass the test as well as the production test code which originally surfaced the problem.

I experienced this exception being thrown when running tests on some instances, but not all of them. I ran the same reproduction unit test in as many different instances as I had easy access to. Test results per instance:

- NA11: Pass (Tested in 1 org)
- NA22: Fail (Tested in 6 orgs)
- NA30: Fail (Tested in 5 orgs)
- NA34: Pass (Tested in 1 org)
- NA35: Pass (Tested in 2 orgs)

### Reproduction Code

Static Resource: Mock_API_Response

```
{
   "total":1,
   "nextOffset":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "company_id":"a"
         , "product_name":"product"
         , "updated":"2017-01-01 02:51:01"
      }
   ]
}
```

Batch Class

```
public without sharing class Callout_Batch implements Database.Batchable<Integer>, Database.stateful, Database.allowsCallouts {

    public Callout_Batch() {

    }

    public List<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        // execute a callout
        String url = 'https://api.example.com/v2/scores?limit=1000&offset=0&api_key=1234';

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setMethod('GET');

        HttpResponse httpResponse = (new Http()).send(request);

        String response = httpResponse.getBody();

        return new List<Integer>();
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Integer> scope) {

    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {  

    }
}
```

Callout Batch Test

```
@isTest
private class Callout_Batch_Test {

    static testmethod void testCallout_Batch() {

         // get the standard user profile id 
        Id profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id;

        String email = 'unit.test.user+345@' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId() + '.test.com';
        User u = new User(
            FirstName           = 'Test',
            LastName            = 'User ',
            Email               = email,
            Username            = email,
            Alias               = 'tuser345',
            Phone               = '503-555-1212',
            ProfileId           = profileId,
            TimeZoneSidKey      = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey        = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey    = 'ISO-8859-1',
            LanguageLocaleKey   = 'en_US'
        );

        insert u;

        system.runas(u) {

            MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock multiMock = new MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock();
            multiMock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            multiMock.setStatusCode(200);
            multiMock.setStaticResource('https://api.example.com/v2/scores/?limit=1000&offset=0&api_key=1234', 'Mock_API_Response');

            Test.startTest();

            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multiMock);            

            Database.executeBatch(new Callout_Batch(), 1);

            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Thrown

```
Class: Callout_Batch_Test
Method Name: testCallout_Batch
Pass/Fail: Fail
Error Message: System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
```

Comment: I just ran into this issue. In my case, In my case, I am using WebService callouts that are called in a Batchable. In my tests, I am creating a User in a testSetup method. All the tests passed in the sandbox. In production, synchronous invocation of the WebService callouts pass, but the tests of the batch fail. Both environments are Summer '17 (v40.0). Unfortunately, I can't downgrade to v33.0 because I'm using features of v40.0. My solution was to eliminate the creation of the User in testSetup. That did the trick. I'm fortunate I have this option. Not sure what I would have done otherwise.